# How can a workbook reopen itself in a separate Excel instance

Tags: excel, vba

I want my workbook to open in its own separate instance of Excel. If it gets opened with other workbooks, it should reopen itself in a new instance, perhaps using a code in the Workbook_Open event. Additionally, the workbook should prevent files from opening in the same instance, perhaps by moving them to a new instance or moving itself to a new one. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Edit:
The purpose of this is that workbooks loaded with code and userforms tend to crash easily causing all other workbooks open in the same instance to crash and lose all unsaved changes and the end user gets frustrated. Another issue is that when the `Application.OnKey` is used, I experienced three problems: 1. shortcut triggers a code that's usually intended to act on the workbook it resides in. This can be solved by checking whether the hosting workbook is the active workbook before running, but it's better to prevent them from running in the first place. 2. common shortcuts can be reassigned to run a custom code, but usually this shouldn't affect other workbooks. 3. problems happen when multiple workbooks that assign same shortcut to custom subs. the most recently open workbook takes over the shortcut action. Also, when the workbook that contains the shortcut is closed, using the shortcut reopens the workbook automatically, which is not a desired! Removing the custom shortcut doesn't solve the problem of multiple workbooks using same shortcut.

Therefore, best solution is to start such workbooks in their own application instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to make an Excel workbook (which was running a timer) reopen itself in another instance of Excel. This was to let the user use the first instance of Excel without the timer interfering. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you need, but that can certainly help you get started. You can find the code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/DecimalTurn/Excel-Pomodoro-Timer/tree/master/src/Pomodoro_Timer.xlsb).

The procedure that you would be interested in is called `OpenItSelfInAnotherInstance` and is located in `OpenItself.bas`.

For it to work you will also need to include the code contained in `API_Maximize.bas`, `API_Sleep.bas` and `UDF_ExcelIntances.bas`. (If you copy-paste, always exclude the line that says :`Attribute VB_Name =...` since it's there only for when you import the *.bas file in from the VBE)

Please let me know if there is anything unclear in there, so I can add some explanations in my answer if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much @DecimalTurn, This seems to be exactly what I wanna do. You saved me a lot of work. I'll give it a try and then mark this as the answer. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: you're a lifesaver. The world is definitely a better place with stakoverflow and people like you :-D. Still second part of the question: how can I detect if other files get open in the new created instance? Or Rather, what's Excel's default behavior when the user double-clicks on a workbook; which instance is used by default?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Regarding the 2nd question: If a user double-clicks on another Excel file and there is more than one instance of Excel open, the new file will by default open in the first instance that was opened among the instances currently open (based on the tests that I've done).